# c# [Win Form] Unable to use multiple properties of same class

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, properties

I created a text editor in which when I increase font size the font style become regular or when I change font family font size become default.
How to solve this problem?

Code that changes font size

```
    float size = float.Parse(toolStripMenuItem3.Text);
        if (checkwritingpad == true)
            WritingBox.SelectionFont = new System.Drawing.Font(WritingBox.SelectionFont.FontFamily, size, FontStyle.Regular);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that changes the font size?

Comment: code is updated on post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I increase font size the font style become regular

Of course it does! You are creating a font with a regular style there! Don't you see?

```
WritingBox.SelectionFont = new 
    System.Drawing.Font(WritingBox.SelectionFont.FontFamily, size,
    FontStyle.Regular);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             ^
             |
         here, see?
```

I think you can store the previous style somewhere first and use that to create the new font object:

```
var style = WritingBox.SelectionFont.Style;
WritingBox.SelectionFont = 
    new System.Drawing.Font(WritingBox.SelectionFont.FontFamily, size,
    style);
```

And you can use a similar method to solve the "font size becomes default" problem.